# function not calling inside event listener

Tags: javascript, html

```
function main() {
    var dict = {};     
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if (document.getElementById("female").checked) { 
            dict["F"]=true;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("male").checked) {
            dict["M"]=true;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("gameA").checked){ 
             start(game.A);
        }
    });
```

So, when the start button is clicked, I want to create a dictionary of some values and then if the gameA box is checked, I want to start the game. However, the start function doesn't seem to work when it's inside the eventListener. The start function should display text on the screen and then play audio. The text shows up, but the audio doesn't play.

If I put the start function outside the event listener, but still inside the main function using:

```
document.getElementById("gameA").addEventListener('click',function () {
    start(game.A);
});
```

Then, the audio works fine. However, I don't know how to allocate the dictionary because if I put the lines that allocate it outside the event listener, it doesn't work for some reason.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Did you check to see if #gameA is really `checked`? That's the condition under which `start` gets called.

Comment: It is. In the first scenario, the game "starts" but the audio doesn't play, and in the second one, the audio plays and everything is fine except then I don't allocate the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like

```
function main() {
    var dict = {};     

        event.preventDefault(); 
        if (document.getElementById("female").checked) { 
            dict["F"]=true;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("male").checked) {
            dict["M"]=true;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("gameA").checked){ 
             start(game.A);
        }
}
```

And HTML like

```
<input type="button" value="StartButton" onclick="main();"/>
```